# Oledb skips the first column of excel file

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have a problem when I try to save an Excel file into a DataTable on C# using OLEDB.

The DataTable doesn't have the first column of my Excel file but have an extra empty column as last column. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. If my Excel file have something like this:

ID, Name, Adress

The DataTable columns are:

Name, Adress, F3(empty)

Here is my function:

```
    public DataTable GetExcel(string[] files, string sheetName, string pathName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            string strConn = string.Empty;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sheetName)) { sheetName = "Sheet1"; }
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(files[i]);
            if (!file.Exists) { throw new Exception("Error, file doesn't exists!"); }
            string extension = file.Extension;
            switch (extension)
            {
                case ".xls":
                    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + file + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
                    break;
                case ".xlsx":
                    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + file + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
                    break;
                default:
                    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + file + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
                    break;
            }
            OleDbConnection cnnxls = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
            OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(string.Format("select * from [{0}$]", sheetName), cnnxls);
            oda.Fill(dataTable);
        }
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Make columns by yourself, like `dataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string)` before calling `oda.Fill(dataTable)`

Comment: It doesn't work, I still have an empty last column and it miss the first one. Thank you so much.

Comment: Adapter guesses table columns from query, and sometimes things like that happen. Do you know the range of your cells? If you do, you can query sheet like this: `string.Format("select * from [{0}$A1:C200]", sheetName)`

Comment: Why not just select the entire sheet?

Comment: @Nino I will never know the range, I tried it anyways and now doesn't create an empty column but still miss the first one, thanks.

Comment: @AdiMohan Still doesn't recognise the first column, thank you

Comment: Incidentally, there is no need to use the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider. Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 will read/write both types of Excel files just fine. You can take that whole switch statement out and just use "Excel 12" in your extended properties for both files types. The driver will sort it out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem was the Excel file, I just copied everything to another Excel file using another computer and worked. I don't know what was wrong.

I hope I can help someone else.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is what happened to you or not, but I can hopefully help someone else.
When I had this bug it was because my csv file had a whitespace at the start of it which made Excel ignore everything after it - which was the entire string that I wanted to use (For some reason, Excel ignores everything that comes after a whitespace in C#).

You can either use Trim, or if you want to be safer, use this Regex to target only words, numbers, and a few more characters:

```
string s = file.ToString().Trim();
string s = new Regex(@"(\w|[0-9]|\\|\/|\.|\:)+").Match(file.ToString()).Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked after writing one value on the first column of the excel. Looks like it skips them when no data is found on the first columns.